# Bootstrap Vue navbar doesn't fill screen

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-vue

I'm using a bootstrap-vue navbar I got from github.

For some reason it doesn't fill the screen. There's whitespace either side. 
How can I extend the navbar to fit the with of the screen?

```
  <template>
    <b-container class="mt-2">
      <b-navbar toggleable="md" type="dark" variant="info">
        <b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>
        <b-collapse is-nav id="nav-collapse">

          <b-navbar-nav>
            <b-nav-item to="/events">Events</b-nav-item>
            <b-nav-item to="/monitor">Monitor</b-nav-item>
            <b-nav-item to="/configuration">Configuration</b-nav-item>

            <b-nav-item to="/comments">Comments</b-nav-item>
            <b-nav-item to="/submit">Submit</b-nav-item>
          </b-navbar-nav>

          <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto" v-if="$store.state.loggedIn">
            <b-nav-text>{{ $store.state.user.username }}</b-nav-text>
            <b-nav-item @click.prevent="logout()">Logout</b-nav-item>
          </b-navbar-nav>

          <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto" v-if="!$store.state.loggedIn">
            <b-nav-item to="/login">Login</b-nav-item>
          </b-navbar-nav>
        </b-collapse>
      </b-navbar>

      <b-container class="mt-1">
        <nuxt/>
      </b-container>

    </b-container>
  </template>

  <script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      logout () {
        this.$store.dispatch('logout')
        this.$router.push('/')
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b-container` has a max-width by default padding on the left and right.

Replace the `b-container` in your template root with a normal div and the padding/white space should go away.

If you want a `b-container` to fill the page, you can add the `fluid` prop which will remove the max-width from the container. 
The `b-container` with the `fluid` prop will still have a small padding each side so that the content doesn't stick to the sides.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks. I do however have a similar issue with the data below the nav bar. Any guess offhand? Thanks again.

Comment: @tomoc4 Think i misunderstood your main issue at first, however the answer i gave still holds true.
I've added some additional text that could solve your 2nd issue.